# 2SXC - Complete Upgrade not completing after 8.x upgrade to 9.2

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc, dotnetnuke-8, dotnetnuke-9

Referring to this article: [Link »](http://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/understanding-upgrade-message-module-upgrade-did-not-complete)

What to do if 10x pressing the button does not do the trick? We have updated the modul from 8.x to 9.2 four days ago and have been pressing the button ever since. It is now still showing "Error: System.Exception: Module upgrade did not complete (read more). Click to complete". Seems like there were no database backups running for this system, so we can't go back.

Thanks for any helpful tipps.

```
2017-07-15T17:41:09 08.05.00 - ----- Upgrade to 08.05.00 started -----
2017-07-15T17:41:11 08.05.00 - Upgrade failed - Sequence contains no matching element
2017-07-15T17:41:11 - set upgrade running - False
2017-07-15T17:41:11 - set upgrade running - False – done
```

Comment: Ok, we were able to reset everything to the state before the update. Would be good to know though what could be going on in the backup. Will try more smaller upgrades from now on instead of skipping a few versions.

Comment: I can't give you a clear answer to this, sorry. 9.3 Pre3 should do a much better job, but you may want to wait till it's out of pre-release.

Answer (score 0):

Should be all fixed in later versions.